# How can I get an array to store a maximum of 10 elements being input by the user with a do-while loop in C?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

So the user is asked to enter a number then after, the user will be able to choose whether or not he/she wants to enter another number to be stored into an array that contains a maximum of 10 numbers. So by the time when either the user will enter "NO" or the array will be full then the program function will stop.
So what I'm trying to display is something like this:

The array in this program is capable of storing 10 numbers

Please enter a number: 22

Another? (Y/N): y

Please enter a number: 29

Another? (Y/N): n

Array is now closed/full

This is my program function

```
void getInput(int array[N], char choice)
{

int i;

    printf("The array in this program is capable of storing 10 numbers\n\n");

    i=0;

    do
    {
        printf("Please enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        printf("Another? (Y/N): \n");
        scanf("%c", &choice);

        if(choice == 'Y' || choice ==  'y'){
            i++;
        }
        else if(choice == 'N' || choice == 'n' || array[i] == array[10]){
            break;
        }
    }while(choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y' && choice != 'N' || choice != 'n');
        printf("Array is now closed/full\n");
    return;
}
```

Comment: You need to specify the array size for the array parameter: `void getInput(int array[10], char choice)`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ afaik, cannot get the array size like that, it decays to an `int*` pointer, need to pass it via template and a reference `template<size_t N> void getinput(int (&array)[N], char choice)`. Or maybe I misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: C != C++ and natural answers for each can be very different. In general, you should only tag the language you are compiling.

Comment: @vsoftco I also thought about the template solution. The reference is what I've been certainly missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, just change this

```
if(choice == 'N' || choice == 'n' || array[i] == array[10])
```

to this

```
if(choice == 'N' || choice == 'n' || i == 9)
```

and remember that indexing is `0` based in c, so `array[10]` is off bounds.

I also see many other errors in your code

1. You evaluate the input to check for `choice` multiple times, that's not needed.
2. Your second `scanf` will eat the left `\n` in the previous step if you press enter after inputing the number.
3. Your `else if` condition presumably checks for the end of the `array` but only when `choice != 'Y' && choice != 'y'`.
4. the `getInput()` function signature doesn't make sense. Instead you could pass the element count of the array and declare `choice` locally in the function.

This is a fixed version of your program

```
void getInput(unsigned int count, int array[count])
{
    unsigned int i;
    char         choice;

    printf("The array in this program is capable of storing %d numbers\n", count);
    i = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("Please enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &array[i++]);

        printf("Another? (Y/N): \n");
        scanf(" %c", &choice);
    } while ((choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y') && (i < count));

    if (i == count)
        printf("Array is now closed / full\n");

    return;
}
```

Comment: scanf() to scan a char will consume `\n` I don't see it been taken care off isn't it?

Comment: @Gopi There are many other problems with this program, look at the `else if` the condition will never be evaluated if `Y` or `y` was input. You can write a detailed report on why this program fails, I authorize you to use my observation too, which is the way to read `10` values only, but this program will still fail for other reasons. Also, why did you delete your answer, just fix it.

Comment: I was wondering why is there a need to prompt the user for `y` or `n` just keep entering numbers and stop after 10 integers :)